code status 204 returns no data - RESTFul API -
I'm trying to submit some data into CreatePurchaseOrders API, screen ID: PO505000
but while i'm submitting the data into postman with POST request it returns 204 No content message, i'm expecting the data been saved inside Purchase order lists, but there is no new data!
the bellow images are screenshots of my endpoints







and my json code inside postman is:
{

"entity": {

    "VendorID": {"value": "V10156"},
    "PurchDate": {"value":"05/21/2024"}
    "Details": [
            {
            "InventoryId": {"value": "1MW644GRY-XL"}, 
            "OrderNbr": {"value": "CD-000391003"}, 
            "RequestedOn": {"value": "5/16/2024"}, 
            "OrderQty": {"value": 2.000}, 

            "VendorPrice": {"value": 20.00},
            "LineNbr": {"value": 20}, 
            "Location": {"value": "07"}, 
            "Customer": {"value": "C00020083"},
            "UOM": {"value": "EA"}
            }
    ]
}
}


The HTTP 204 No Content success status response code indicates that a request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to navigate away from its current page. It means your created purchase order has succeeded without problem.

@BenchVue but nothing been added to my purchase order list

Do you have api documentation URL?

no i dont have it

I think perhaps you're operating on a misconception on how this page works.  It isn't direct injection of data into the ERP rather it is a processing page where you would select available records that can be processed into Purchase orders.  The top level fields such as VendorID and PurchDate would be used to filter the available records before processing.  Check here for an example
